# NSXMLParser not finding closing tag

Tags: ios

Im trying to fetch list of content from xml web source . Im using NSXMLParser atm.

here is the code :

```
- (void)main
{

    self.workingArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.workingPropertyString = [NSMutableString string];


    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://myxmlwebsite.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];    
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    bool result = [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"result is ok for xml parse : %@", result ? @"Yes" : @"No");


    if (![self isCancelled])
    {
        self.appRecordList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.workingArray];
        SubCategoryViewController *subCategoryViewController;
        subCategoryViewController.entries = self.appRecordList;
        [subCategoryViewController.tableView reloadData];

    }

    self.workingArray = nil;
    self.workingPropertyString = nil;
    self.dataToParse = nil;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                        namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                       qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
                                        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kUser])
    {

        self.workingEntry = [[UserFetchAppRecord alloc] init];
    }
    _elementsToParse = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        kid,ktitle, nil];
    self.storingCharacterData = [_elementsToParse containsObject:elementName];
}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                     qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (self.workingEntry)
    {

        if (self.storingCharacterData)
        {
            NSString *trimmedString = [self.workingPropertyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                       [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            [self.workingPropertyString setString:@""];
            if ([elementName isEqualToString:kid])
            {
                self.workingEntry.ids = trimmedString;
               NSLog(@"id : %@" , trimmedString);
            }
            else if ([elementName isEqualToString:ktitle])
            {        
                self.workingEntry.title = trimmedString;
                 NSLog(@"ktitle : %@" , trimmedString);

            }



        }
        else if ([elementName isEqualToString:kUser])
        {
            NSLog(@"inside elementName isEqualToString:kUser");
            [self.workingArray addObject:self.workingEntry];
            NSUInteger self_workingArrayCount = [self.workingArray count];
            self.workingEntry = nil;
        }
    }

}
```

Now at console if i run program i get these results :

"result is ok for xml parse = true"

"id : 1"

"ktitle : usertitle"

.
.
.

but the result of closing tab no showing in console, this one "inside elementName isEqualToString:kUser".

hows that possible ?

the tag of my xml are like this :

```
<Main>
<user>
<id></id>
<title></title>
</user>
<user>
<id></id>
<title></title>
</user>
.....
</Main>
```

Comment: change `else if` to `if([elementName isEqualToString:kUser])`

Comment: ooooops !!! my huge mistake ! thanks man , add in az answer plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `else if ([elementName isEqualToString:kUser])` in

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

to `if ([elementName isEqualToString:kUser])`.

`self.storingCharacterData` become `YES` when element `id` or `title` starts. So when element `user` ends `self.storingCharacterData` will be `YES`, and `else if ([elementName isEqualToString:kUser])` wont work.